# Conditional Statements difference

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any difference between below two statements

```
if (null != obj)
```

and

```
if (obj != null)
```

If both treated same which will be preferable?

Comment: They can be different if an idiot overrode the != operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference here is the code generated. The two will not generate the exact same code, but in practice this will have no bearing on the results or performance of the two statements.

However, if you create your own types, and override the inequality operator, and do a poor job, then it will matter.

Consider this:

```
public class TestClass
{
    ...

    public static bool operator !=(TestClass left, TestClass right)
    {
        return !left.Equals(right);
    }
}
```

In this case, if the first argument to the operator is null, ie. `if (null != obj)`, then it will crash with a `NullReferenceException`.

So to summarize:

- The code generated is different
- The performance and end results should be the same

  - Except when you have broken code in the type involved

Now, the reason I think you're asking is that you've seen code from C, which typically had code like this:

```
if (null == obj)
```

Note that I switched to equality check here. The reason is that a frequent bug in programs written with old C compilers (these days they tend to catch this problem) would be to switch it around and forget one of the equal characters, ie. this:

```
if (obj = null)
```

This assigns `null` to the variable instead of comparing it. The best way to combat this bug, back then, would be to switch it around, since you can't assign anything to `null`, it's not a variable. ie. this would fail to compile:

```
if (null = obj)
```

Answer (score 23):

The first is a Yoda condition. Use it you should not.

Answer (score 4):

No, but the second way is more common and more readable (and more logical in my opinion)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not. It's exactly the same.

The style `null == obj` is sometimes just used to prevent the common typo `obj = null` to not accidently assign null to a variable, but with `!=` there's absolutely no reason to do so.

In .NET it won't actually compile for the typo `obj = null`.
So the compiler prevents you from   accidently doing it.

The [Yoda condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2430307#2430307) comes originally from other languages, where this compiler feature is missing.

Comment: And the compiler will warn you if you accidentally use `=` in place of `==`.

Comment: Yep I was just going to add that for .NET.

Comment: they're not exactly the same, if obj overrides the operator concerned, the outcome can be different.

Comment: What are you you talking about? Read my answer before you downvote it. The OP was asking about `null != obj' and `obj != null` and these conditions are exactly the same.

Comment: @LukeH: Actually, the compiler will *error* if you accidentally use = in place of == the vast majority of the time, because you can't have a non-Boolean in an "if" statement condition. The *warning* only happens if the type of the assignment expression is convertible to Boolean, for example, if you do "if (b1 = b2)" where b1 and b2 are both bool. If you do "if(obj = null)" then that's an error because object is not convertible implicitly to Boolean.

Comment: @Eric: I thought the same as LukeH, so didn't know there were cases where you were able to use = instead of == in an if statement. But now that you made us aware, isn't this a potentially dangerous behavior? I personally never needed to do "if (boolA = boolB)" in an if statement, so if I did, I would have done it by mistake. Do you know why C# team decided to allow this case for bool assignments? Just curious.

Comment: @Joan: That's why it is a warning; because it is potentially dangerous.  But it should be legal. Consider chained assignment: "b = c = d;" If you want that to work then that means that the value of "c = d" has to be the value assigned to c. Therefore "if (c = d)" should be legal if the value is convertible to bool; the expression has a value, so why shouldn't it be legal to use in a place where a boolean value is needed?

Comment: @Eric: Thanks I see what you mean, when you look at it that way it makes sense. I also didn't know there was a warning about this. But if you wanted you could still disable that case if used in if statements, but chose to have consistent language semantics?

Comment: @Joan: Sure, we could have outlawed all assignments in "if" statements. Frankly I'm not particularly thrilled by the "assignment is an expression" feature in the first place; I don't think it adds a lot of value and it can cause weird bugs if you don't understand the order in which the side effect of assignment happens.

Answer (score 1):

They are exactly the same.

Some people prefer to put the null as the first part of the expression to avoid errors like this

```
if (obj = null)  // should be obj == null
```

But of course this doesn't apply to the `!=` operator, so in your example it's just a difference of style.

Comment: and in C# if (obj = null) is a compile error, because "obj = null" doesn't evaluate to a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

First type of statement came from **C/C++**, where was possible to pass not boolean values to condition verification. E.g. anything not 0 was true, and zero was false:

```
if (5) { } // true
if (0) { } // false
```

Sometimes it created problems if you forgot to type one '=' char:

```
if (x = 5) { }   // this was true always and changed x value
if (x == 5) { }  // this was true, if x was equal to 5
```

So, Yoda syntax was used, to receive compiler error in case one '=' was missed:

```
if (5 = x) { }   // this was generating compiler error for absent-minded programmers
if (5 == x) { }  // this was true, if x was equal to 5
```

**C#** allow only boolean value in conditions, So

```
if (x = 5) { }   // this won't compile
if (x == 5) { }  // this is true, if x was equal to 5
```

What about boolean types?

```
if (y = true) { }
if (y == true) { }
```

Well, this is useless code, because you can just write if (y).
Conclusion: Yoda syntax is gone with C/C++ and you do not need to use it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The use of the first form

```
if (blah == obj)
```

stems from the days when compilers would not catch  `if (obj = blah)`  i.e. unintentional assignment, unless compile warning level was set to maximum