# What is better coding standard x != null or null != x?

Tags: c#, java, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conditional Statements difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957770/conditional-statements-difference)

I wanted to know what is a good way of writing the code :

```
X != null
```

or

```
null != X
```

Both of them will do same thing, but sometimes I see people write `null != X` so I am not sure what is a good way of writing it.

Comment: In C: `if (X)` or `if (X != NULL)`, in C# and Java: `if (X != null)`. It's more natural.

Comment: While I am interested to see perhaps enlightening justifications for this. I think one would be misguided to claim either as **the good style**. The is one of those things that comes down to personal preference.

Comment: Duplicate of lots of questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=yoda

Comment: this is an opinion not a fact

Comment: I think this is a very legitimate question that should be answered, or, minimally migrated to programmers.

Comment: All about oppinion. But actually. You can avoid an unwanted assignment by going with null != X. That is, if you accidently forget the !. Meaning you could accidently write x = null, but null = X would cause an error. This is is the only difference as I see it. Some people call null != X yoda coding or yoda condition ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The convention of reversing comparisons as `null != X` comes mainly from C where

```
if(X == NULL) {
```

is easily confused with

```
if(X = NULL) {
```

which is a valid statement that overwrites X with NULL instead of checking if it's NULL.

Turning the comparison the other way;

```
if(NULL == X) {
```

works just as well, but confusing the equals operator with assignment

```
if(NULL = X) {
```

will actually give a compilation error.

Comment: Glad to see that someone understands this - it is not a matter of style as some suggested - it was and is still a 'guard' against accidentally writing an assignment instead of a comparison.  This is not useful at all in C#, but only in C as Joachim stated.

Answer (score 7):

Common practice is to have the variable on the left-hand side: `X != null`. Putting the variable on the right-hand side is often called a "[Yoda Condition](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html)".

Comment: +1 for interesting name, Yoda Condition!

Answer (score 2):

Putting the literal on the left means that if you accidentally use = instead of == the compiler will complain. Also it can save on explicit null checks, for example (in Java)

```
if("hello".equals(someString))
```

returns false if `someString` is null.

Comment: I've seen a lot of people on SO advocating for not doing this. Doing what you state is more likely to hide bugs. Null checks, while cumbersome, are recommended in these cases.

Answer (score 1):

I always use the format

```
<VAR> (!)= <VAL>
```

and never invert the order.

Answer (score 1):

As you already said, both of them will do the same thing. The questions is about style so. Personally I would say x!=null is more readable.