# Difference between FALSE==var and var==FALSE

Tags: difference

I've always wondered why some programmers use `FALSE == var` rather than `var == FALSE` in conditionals. IS there any performance gain in using the former? The latter format is more readable, I believe.

Comment: No performance difference, but not compiled if written "FALSE = var" by mistake. Looks ugly.

Comment: Specify which language. But in all the languages that I know, there's no difference. It's called [Yoda Conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions), some people use it to avoid accidentally using `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957770/conditional-statements-difference) you may see.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking for null - what order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983573/checking-for-null-what-order)

Answer (score 2):

This is simply to avoid the frequent error of accidentally typing `var = FALSE` instead of `var == FALSE`, thus assigning `FALSE` to the `var` and guaranteeing that the condition be true.

Answer (score 2):

Some languages allow assignment where a condition is expected (C, for instance);

```
if (a = 5)
```

This led (at one point) to a common class of bugs, because of course the above *assigns* 5 to `a` and then, since `5` is not zero, goes into the body of the `if`. What the author meant, of course, was

```
if (a == 5)
```

If you write it the other way, the code can't be compiled:

```
if (5 = a)
```

...since you can't assign to a constant. So that flags up the bug and you fix it to

```
if (5 == a)
```

With any modern (or even relatively old) compiler, there's no need to do this. Use lint settings that warn you about assignments where comparisons are expected.

Comment: I'm sure i read somewhere that where comparing like:
var == FALSE is faster comparison  rather than FALSE== var .T.J Answer will do more clear about this.

Comment: @Aman: No, it's no faster in any environment I've ever heard of. Both sides of the operator must still be evaluated, and the resulting values must be compared, regardless of which way you write it.

Answer (score 0):

No difference in meaning or performance there is.

Just avoiding the accidental `var = FALSE` assignment in case they make a typo programmers who use this style are.

[Yoda conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) some people call them. Recommend them I do not. But if useful you find them, use them you may.