# Is there any benefit to reversing the order of variable and value?

Tags: c#

I am not a seasoned developer. But I've always heard that part of intent with writing code is making it readable. This is a small example, but it puzzled me and I wanted to understand if there is some benefit I'm not seeing because I'm so green. I was reviewing a more Sr. developer's code and I saw this:

`if (0 == intValue)`

Again, this is a small thing. It appeared like 10 different times in 20 lines of code. But we want to test the value of `intValue`, but we express it here as if we're we want to test the value of 0. To me, this is the opposite of the way people think, and it becomes less readable. Is there a good reason to write this way?

Comment: Not in C#, no. Basically this is a hang-over from languages where `if (intValue = 0)` would silently compile but not do what you expect it to. My guess is that the developer whose code you're reviewing has come from such a language. And while it's subjective, I agree with you: this is less readable, and it would be better to write it in the more natural order.

Comment: If you ever have a question on whether it makes a difference, you can always compare at [Sharplab](https://sharplab.io). Check the generated IL between both versions. And if they're different (they're not in this case) then you could run them through [Benchmarkdotnet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) to performance to see if it's a meaningful impact.

Comment: This is known as a [Yoda condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions)

Comment: @MartinSmith: You mean "A Yoda condition, this is called."

Comment: Even if there was some benefit, the fact that it's *non-obvious* would immediately discount it as something to emulate. (If there was a benefit and it didn't require any thought, you should expect modern compilers to provide it without you having to do anything)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional Statements difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957770/conditional-statements-difference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historically, this added a small amount of safety to the code on many platforms. Imagine you wrote the condition the more "natural" way:

```
if (intValue == 0)
```

Sometimes, during long sessions, one's brain can play tricks on them, and it becomes easy to mistake assignment for equality:

```
if (intValue = 0)
```

This is obviously wrong now, but when you reach the point where you make the typo ***it can be surprisingly hard to spot***.

In addition to the obvious unintended change to `intValue`, this has the less-obvious problem that on many platforms it will **always** result in `false`, without any regard for the intended comparison. This is because for most platforms the result of an assignment expression is the assigned value, and the `0` value is allowed to be interpreted as `false`. *Sometimes this second factor can act to hide both issues from testing for a long time.*

Writing the expression in the reverse (Yoda) order protects us from this, since it's not legal to have a literal on the left-hand side of an assignment on pretty much any platform.

*Thankfully, this is much less of an issue for C# specifically.*

With C# the mistaken code will result in a compiler error by default, because `if(0)` is not legal out of the box. However, it's possible to contrive examples where it does compile: if you're working with a boolean constant, if this is just part of much larger expression where the `int` result would be legal, if you've defined an implicit conversion to bool, etc.

---

I also want to talk about the scare quotes around "natural". I include them because there's really nothing natural about programming languages. These are engineered and contrived platforms, and if anything seems natural it's because we've trained ourselves to see them that way. If we can train ourselves to find one version as natural, we can train ourselves to see the other version that way, as well.

For this reason, some people still like to have the habit of always using the "safe" version — *even on platforms where it is not needed* —  because it helps them spot potential mistakes on platforms they may also use where it *does* still matter. **Javascript** is a common example here.

That said, I still tend write the less-safe version :/

Comment: Did you mis-read the question as being about C? Cause `if (intValue = 0)` is invalid syntax in C#.

Comment: I did not mistake this for C. I was trying to explain how the pattern originated. But I see the confusion, so I made a few edits to clarify.

Comment: IIRC, `if (boolValue = false)` is still legal in C#, but at least you'll get a warning that the `if` block will never execute.

Comment: @dan04 - you get "warning CS0665: Assignment in conditional expression is always constant; did you mean to use == instead of = " in that case

Answer (score 1):

In C# it is really useless to write these unnatural statements since the compiler already emits an error for non-boolean checks. Consider the following code:

```
int intValue = 5;
if (intValue = 6)
{
}
```

This causes the compilation error

```
Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'
```

The reason is obvious: `intValue = 6` **is an assignment and returns an integer value**, which cannot be converted to `bool`. Hence the compilation error. So you will spot the problem immediately.

The sitaution is more delicate with the `boolean` checks, however. Consider

```
bool boolValue = true;
if (boolValue = false)
{
}
```

This time the compiler emits a *warning*:

```
Warning CS0665: Assignment in conditional expression is always constant; 
did you mean to use == instead of = ?
```

To prevent overlooking this warning and the unintented results, one can [treat warnings as errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings).